# AVL Delete Function not working (segmentation error)

Tags: c++, avl-tree

Greeting!

I am trying to construct a class for an AVL Binary Search Tree. Everything is alright up until the point I have to construct the Delete node function for it.

It's reading from a text file (Insert function works fine) and duplicate words are stored into an amount variable in each node.

When the program is about to execute the delete function it crashes.

I ran it through the debugger and it gives me a segmentation error which I cannot locate. From the debugger call stack, I think it probably is located in one of these functions, but I can't seem to find it.

Here is the code for the rotation functions and the delete function. I'm sure it's in one of these as that's what the debugger is showing me. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Rotation Functions:

```
AVLnode* AVL::RR_rotation(AVLnode* rootPtr)
{
   AVLnode* temp1 = rootPtr->left;
   AVLnode* temp2 = temp1->right;
   temp1->right = rootPtr;
   rootPtr->left = temp2;
   rootPtr->height = maxH(Height(rootPtr->left), Height(rootPtr->right)) + 1;
   temp1->height = maxH(Height(temp1->left), Height(temp1->right)) + 1;
   return temp1;
}

AVLnode* AVL::LL_rotation(AVLnode* rootPtr)
{
    AVLnode* temp1 = rootPtr->right;
    AVLnode* temp2 = temp1->left;
    temp1->left = rootPtr;
    rootPtr->right = temp2;
    rootPtr->height = maxH(Height(rootPtr->left), Height(rootPtr->right)) + 1;
    temp1->height = maxH(Height(temp1->left), Height(temp1->right)) + 1;
    return temp1;
}

AVLnode* AVL::LR_rotation(AVLnode* rootPtr)
{
   AVLnode* temp;
   temp = rootPtr->left;
   rootPtr->left = RR_rotation(temp);
   return LL_rotation(rootPtr);
}

AVLnode* AVL::RL_rotation(AVLnode* rootPtr) 
{
   AVLnode* temp;
   temp = rootPtr->right;
   rootPtr->right = LL_rotation(temp);
   return RR_rotation(rootPtr);
}
```

And here's the Delete function:

```
AVLnode* AVL::Delete(AVLnode* rootPtr, std::string word)
{
    if (rootPtr == nullptr)
    {
        return rootPtr;
    }
    if (word < rootPtr->word )
    {
        rootPtr->left = Delete(rootPtr->left, word);
    }
    else if(word > rootPtr->word )
    {
        root->right = Delete(rootPtr->right, word);
    }
    else
    {
        if (rootPtr->amount > 1)
        {
            rootPtr->amount = rootPtr->amount - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((rootPtr->left == nullptr) && (rootPtr->right == nullptr))
            {
                AVLnode* temp = rootPtr;
                delete temp;
                rootPtr = nullptr;
            }
            else if (rootPtr->left == nullptr)
            {
                AVLnode* temp = rootPtr;
                delete temp;
                rootPtr = rootPtr->right;
            }
            else if (rootPtr->right == nullptr)
            {
                AVLnode* temp = rootPtr;
                delete temp;
                rootPtr = rootPtr->left;
            }
            else
            {
                AVLnode* temp = FindMin(rootPtr->right);
                rootPtr->word = temp->word;
                rootPtr->right = Delete(rootPtr->right, temp->word);
            }
        }
    }
    rootPtr->height = 1 + maxH(Height(rootPtr->left),  Height(rootPtr->right));
    int balance = getBalance(rootPtr);
    if ((balance > 1) && (getBalance(rootPtr->left) >= 0))
    {
        return RR_rotation(rootPtr);
    }
    if ((balance > 1) &&  (getBalance(rootPtr->left) < 0))
    {
        return LR_rotation(rootPtr);
    }
    if ((balance < -1) && (getBalance(rootPtr->right) <= 0))
    {
        return RR_rotation(rootPtr);
    }
    if ((balance < -1) && (getBalance(rootPtr->right) > 0))
    {
        return RL_rotation(rootPtr);
    }
  return rootPtr;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried **stepping through your code** using the debugger? That should tell you pretty quickly where the seg fault is.

Comment: *Everything is alright up until the point I have to construct the Delete node function for it* -- Until we see a [mcve] with sample data that causes the crash, the claim of everything being fine is still up for debate..

Comment: Well, I'm only saying that because when I comment the call of the Delete function out of main(), the rest of the program works as it was intended

Comment: @BillSiopis -- C++ does not work this way.  Removing functions does not translate into the code working correctly.  Maybe the function is revealing an issue with the way your tree was created or updated.   Many times we see posts from persons that when they remove, say, the destructor, "everything is working".  But when you dig deeper, it wasn't the function that was removed, instead the removed function revealed the bug(s).

Answer (score 2):

I spot at least a couple of points that could lead to the problem:

```
        AVLnode* temp = rootPtr;
        delete temp;
        rootPtr = rootPtr->right;
```

here you have deleted the area of memory that rootPtr points to. Therefore, whatever rootPtr was pointing too is now released and you must not access it.

One safe alternative is:

```
        else if (rootPtr->left == nullptr)
        {
            AVLnode* temp = rootPtr->right;
            delete rootPtr;
            rootPtr = temp;
        }
        else if (rootPtr->right == nullptr)
        {
            AVLnode* temp = rootPtr->left;
            delete rootPtr;
            rootPtr = temp;
        }
```